# How to get fancybox to cycle through photos within the same filter category instead of the whole list?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-isotope, fancybox-2

I apologise in advance as I know this question has been asked before, but I just couldn't figure out how to apply the answer to my own code. So here is my [website](http://www.freddieblackmanphotography.com/). As you can see by selecting a filter and clicking on one of the photos, cycling through them goes through the whole album as opposed to the photos within the same filter category. Any ideas on how to fix this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
<body>  
    <div class="portfolioFilter">
            <a class="filterTitle">Filter by Category:</a>
        <ul>    
            <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="current">All Categories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".landscape">Landscape</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".wildlife">Wildlife</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".travel">Travel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".sport">Sport</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".events">Events</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="current">All Categories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".landscape">Landscape</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".wildlife">Wildlife</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".travel">Travel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".sport">Sport</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".events">Events</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>   
        </ul>   
    </div>
    <div class="portfolioContainer">
        <div class="events">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/openmic1.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/openmic1.jpg" alt="openmic1"/></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="events">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/openmic2.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/openmic2.jpg" alt="openmic2"/></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="events">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/openmic3.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/openmic3.jpg" alt="openmic3"/></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="events">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/openmic4.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/openmic4.jpg" alt="openmic4"/></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="events">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/openmic5.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/openmic5.jpg" alt="openmic5"/></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="eventsl">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/openmic6.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/openmic6.jpg" alt="openmic6"/></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="travel">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/chicagoskyline.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/chicagoskylinethumb.jpg" alt="chicagoskyline"/></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="landscape">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/sunriserehoboth.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/sunriserehoboththumb.jpg" alt="Sunrise at Rehoboth Beach"/></a>
        </div>      
        <div class="landscape">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/trailersunset.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/trailersunsetthumb.jpg" alt="Trailer at Sunset"/></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="travel">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/atopthevoortrekker.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/atopthevoortrekkerthumb.jpg" alt="Atop the Voortrekker"/></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="wildlife">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/cheetahatkruger.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/cheetahatkrugerthumb.jpg" alt="Cheetah at Kruger"/></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="travel">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/buckinghamfountain.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/buckinghamfountainthumb.jpg" alt="Buckingham Fountain"/></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="landscape">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/wintersunrise.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/wintersunrisethumb.jpg" alt="Winter Sunrise"/></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="wildlife">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/leopardpilanesberg.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/leopardpilanesbergthumb.jpg" alt="Leopard at Pilanesberg"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="wildlife">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/leopardpilanesberg2.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/leopardpilanesberg2thumb.jpg" alt="Leopard at Pilanesberg II"/></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="travel">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/greatzimbabwe.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/greatzimbabwethumb.jpg" alt="Great Zimbabwe"/></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="sport">
            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="images/gallery/bmx.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/bmxthumb.jpg" alt="BMX"/></a>
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
<br><br><br>  

<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="scripts/jquery.headroom.js"></script>




<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/fancybox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            helpers:  {
                title : {
                type : 'inside'
                },
            overlay : {
                showEarly : false
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/isotope.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function(){
        var $container = $('.portfolioContainer');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: '*',
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
        });

        $('.portfolioFilter a, .portfolioFilterSmall a').click(function(){
            $('.portfolioFilter .current').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');

            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $container.isotope({
                filter: selector,
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 750,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    queue: false
                }
             });
             return false;
        }); 
    });

</script>
```

Comment: why not just hide all the lis that are not matching your filter

Comment: You need to set the same `data-fancybox-group` for each group you want to cycle. In other words, as in their parent container like `events`, `travel`, `wildlife` .... so far all `data-fancybox-group` are set to `gallery` so no matter you filter the parent, the gallery will show all

Comment: Thanks JFK! I can't believe I didn't try that. Much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again JFK but now when "All Categories" is selected the fancybox gallery only cycles through the photos of the same category. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue like this one.And I think I see the area I need to target..I've created a gallery page with 4 separate sections on the page.Each gallery only shows 5 thumbnails and the rest of the images hidden within.The problem is the entire gallery is viewed by clicking any thumbnail..I just want the images in that gallery to be viewed.Here is the code I'm using to create the gallery..using a different rel="name" for each gallery of images.